# Track Facebook link share from php

Tags: javascript, php, facebook-share

I want to check if the user actually shared on facebook the post ( not only clicking on the button ).
I've been checking the fb script and couldn't find a solution that will work all the time. Is there another way to check it besides the FB.ui script ?

```
document.getElementById('shareBtn').onclick = function() {
  FB.ui({
    display: 'popup',
    method: 'share',
    href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
  }, function(response){console.log(response)});
}
```

Comment: Close to asking users the rights to read all their posts and check them all, I don't think it is possible. And I'm not even sure you can do that with FB

Comment: But if you want get the shared count from facebook, you can get it with this API -> https://www.sharedcount.com/api-docs/getting-started

Comment: @drosanda Thanks, I will take a look over sharecount